# How to use xlsxwriter .add_table() method with a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, xlsxwriter

my data is dataframe ' how can i do it ?

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test1.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("sheli22")
worksheet.add_table('B3:F7', {'data': data,'style': 'Table Style Light 17','header_row': False})

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

According the xlsxwriter Documentation Section covering the `.add_table()` method, it expects that "the data structure should be an list of lists" ([link to docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html)).

To create this list of lists from your dataframe, it will be necessary to use `.T` to transpose the dataframe and then `.tolist()` to convert the transposed dataframe into a list of lists.

I have a fully reproducible example using a sample dataframe below.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'b':[2,3,4,5,6],
                   'c':[3,4,5,6,7],
                   'd':[4,5,6,7,8],
                   'e':[5,6,7,8,9]})

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test1.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("sheli22")
worksheet.add_table('B3:F7', {'data': data.values.T.tolist(),'style': 'Table Style Light 17','header_row': False})

workbook.close()
```

With Expected Output:

[image: Expected test1.xlsx]

Comment: Hi'if I tray to lode the dadaframe from csv , its not working good , maybe you have a solution ?

Comment: I'd recommend using [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to load your .csv file as a dataframe.  Then perhaps print the dataframe to view the structure and troubleshoot from there.  Perhaps you don't want the .T on your dataframe?

Comment: What happens if the dataframe is larger/smaller than the specified interval 'B3:F7'? Thanks

Comment: @Dudelstein, it only writes what is in the range of the table.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative, use ExcelWriter:

```
 with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter') as ew:
    data.to_excel(ew, sheet_name=sheet_name, **kwargs)
    worksheet = ew.sheets[sheet_name]
    options = dict(columns=[{'header': c} for c in sheet_df.columns], ...)

    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, data.shape[0], data.shape[1] - 1, options=options)
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, as it doesn't need to provide the data in worksheet.add_table call, that has already been done in sheet_df.to_excel.
Note, the lower right corner of the table is sheet_df.shape[0] without -1, as the header of the dataframe is not counted in the shape of the dataframe. 

The above code as it is will not work, having inconsistent variable names. data.to_excel should be sheet_df.to_excel

Answer (score 1):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

worksheet.add_table(start_row,start_col,end_row,end_col,{'style':'Table style light 16','header_row': False})
```

`start_row` is where your starting row of excel from where your table starts, `start_col` is the same as `start_row`, and `end_row` is `start_row+(len(data frame))` and `end_col` is `start_col + len(data frame.columns)`