# Having Trouble Writing Table to Excel with Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Hi I am trying to create a table in excel using a dataframe from another excel spreadsheet and writing the table to a new one.  I believe my code is correct but the table isn't writing to the new excel spreadsheet. Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what's wrong?

```
import xlsxwriter

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as pxl
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
path = '/Users/benlong/Downloads/unemployment.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(path)
rows = df.shape[0]
columns = df.shape[1]
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('UE2.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
ws.add_table(0,0,rows,columns, {'df': df})
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your dataframe to list . By using `df.values.tolist()` and use the key `data`.

In your case ,  you also should set the header of df and avoid getting a nan value error.
eg:

```
import xlsxwriter as xlw

# while got NaN/Inf values from ur dataframe , u'll get a value of '#NUM!' instead in saved excel
wb = xlw.Workbook('UE2.xlsx',{'nan_inf_to_errors': True})
ws = wb.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
cell_range = xlw.utility.xl_range(0, 0, rows, columns-1)
header = [{'header': str(di)} for di in df.columns.tolist()]
ws.add_table(cell_range, {'header_row': True,'first_column': False,'columns':header,'data':df.values.tolist()})
wb.close()
```

Comment: Awesome that worked.  Is there a way for those Nan values to just be left blank?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [How to use xlsxwriter .add_table() method with a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052184/how-to-use-xlsxwriter-add-table-method-with-a-dataframe)

You can try converting the dataframe to a list of lists and use the `data` keyword.

```
ws.add_table(0,0,rows,columns, {'data': df.values.T.tolist()})
```